# Sitecore WeBlog Blog Feeds with Custom Entry templates

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2, weblog

I have implemented WeBlog for sitecore and created custom templates that inherit from Entry, Comment and Category. The RSS Feeds aren't displaying any data now. I did change the query in RSS-Feeds Data Items Field to use the CustomEntry's TemplateID.

I also verified that the query is correct by using XPath builder. Any idea what's wrong?

```
query:/sitecore/content/Home/Blog//*[@@templateid = '{6CF60F32-967D-4CCE-9878-13E2B9B6B2D5}']
```

Comment: Please add a comment if you are going to down vote.

Comment: Just a hint for possible close voters: SiteCore is a high-end CMS and these type of questions can only be asked by or are useful for developers, not for normal users. Migration to Superuser.com is not correct. See also [this MSO post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291566/how-to-report-invalid-downvotes)

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. Had to go to Standard Values of the "Custom Blog Entry", go to Presentation and setup RSS Feed design under"Feeds".